# Random number displayed before my sorting

Tags: c++

I am trying to input 10 numbers and then call the function(sorting) to sort them in ascending order. After sorting it, the main program will also call the function getAvg to average the numbers in the array. However, after putting 10 values into the array. There are some random numbers displayed before my output.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void sorting(int array[]) {
    int t;
    int x=0;

    for (x=0; x<10; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<9; y++)
        {
            if(array[y]>array[y+1])
            {
                t=array[y];
                array[y]=array[y+1];
                array[y+1]=t;
            }
        }
    }
}

double getAvg(int array[]) {
    double sum=0;
    double avg=0;
    for (int j=0;j<10;j++){
        sum=sum+array[j];
    }
    avg=sum/10;
    return avg;
}


int main()
{
    int input=0;
    int array[10];
    double avg=0;
    printf("%s","Enter the 10 temperatures \n");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        scanf("%i",&input);
        array[i]=input;
    }

    sorting(array);    
    avg = getAvg(array);

    for (int k=0;k<=10;k++){
        cout<<array[k-1]<<" ";
    }

    printf("%s %.2lf %s","The average is ",avg, ".");
}
```

Comment: Side note: your code is **a mess**. Try to work in a more organized manner, it will reveal a lot of the bugs **before** they actually take place during runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is in this code:

```
for (int k=0;k<=10;k++){
    cout<<array[k-1]<<" ";
}
```

Notice that on the first iteration of the loop, you'll have `k=0`, so this tries to print out array index -1. This results in undefined behavior - technically speaking, anything can happen - and in your case it's reading garbage data from before the start of the array.

To fix this, change the loop bounds so that they properly range over the array:

```
for (int k=0; k < 10;k++){
    cout<<array[k]<<" ";
}
```

My guess is that you realized that you were reading too far and tried to fix this by subtracting one from the array index, which just introduced a new bug. Hopefully this corrects this!

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int k=0;k<=10;k++){
    cout<<array[k-1]<<" ";
}
```

You are showing from -1 to 9, which means 11 values. The 1st value (array[-1]) was not initialized.

You need to change the k<=10 by k<10 and print array[k] instead of array[k-1]:

```
for (int k=0;k<10;k++){
    cout<<array[k]<<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are printing the elements at positions `-1` through `9` of your array. There is no position `-1`.